# Site won't scroll down in chrome, but works fine in all other browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, scroll

My Wordpress site: othodesign.com

Isn't scrolling down for some reason at all, it's working completely fine on internet explorer, but on google chrome it's refusing to scroll down at all. Please help me! I don't know what to do.

Comment: Also, can someone tell me how I can make the navbar at the top stick for mobile sites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have some sort of caching issue here; the site scrolls just fine for me using Chrome. Have you tried viewing the site in an incognito window to see if the problem persists on your end? Hit Control-shift-N to open an incognito window on a Windows machine.

Comment: You can also press ctrl-f5 to do a cache-less refresh in Chrome.

Comment: Hi, yeah I tried doing that but it's still not scrolling down for some reason

Comment: Disable all your Chrome extensions to rule out any extension issue, also, what version of Chrome do you use?

Comment: I just disabled my extensions, yet it's still not working, I have the latest version of Chrome, it was completely fine before, and I was trying to edit some css to make it work for mobile and it stopped working smoothly, it only scrolls up smoothly, but to scroll down I have to try hard

Comment: PLEASE HELP, is it smooth scrolling for you guys up and down?

Comment: It looks like you might be working on the site now because some JavaScript errors have started popping up that weren't there before and it looks like your smooth scrolling links aren't working right now. Still working on it, or stuck?

Comment: Removing `overflow:hidden` from my CSS code resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I updated Chrome to 61.0.3163.49 it the issue was resolved.