# Wordpress site won't scroll in chrome, using theme montana

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-chrome, plugins

I have been tasked with fixing this site. It is a WordPress site and I plan to rebuild the site not on WordPress. However for the time being the scroll issue needs fixed. The site: www.h2bsafetycentre.com

We have tested it across mac and windows and it won't scroll on Chrome. We have looked at the possibility it is a cacheing issue like others questions suggest however we have all cleared cache and tried across multiple machines. It will scroll on every other browser.

I have tried to change the overflow-y to auto !important and I have tried turning off each plugin to see if that is the issue. None of this has worked.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Looks like when this issue has come up in the past it's been a caching issue - have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45226767/site-wont-scroll-down-in-chrome-but-works-fine-in-all-other-browsers

Comment: Hi, It is not a caching issue as it happens across multiple devices and we have all cleared the cache.

Comment: Scrolling by directly dragging the scrollbar works fine, so it is not an overflow issue to begin with, I suppose. Might rather be some JavaScript that interferes with the scroll event ...

Comment: Well, the scrolling works when the preloader and the loading screen comes up... So check on that code maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open developer console, click into event listeners then load the page.  You can navigate down the list to mousewheel events.  You will notice that SmoothScroll.min.js is loading a window event - if you remove that you should be able to scroll.  I'd suggest removing or configuring SmoothScroll correctly to resolve your scroll issue.

Comment: press f12 in your browser, then navigate to the event listeners tab. Also, if this answers your question could you accept my answer? :)

Comment: and I just found the file in the FTP! Thank you so so much

Comment: No worries - glad I could help.